# Mysql timediff with min

Tags: mysql

I'm making a query to monitor ongoing and expecting file uploads.
Here is what i'm making:

```
select time_to_sec(min(timediff(now(), f.SubmittedDate)))/60 FROM dbtable f WHERE f.Status = 'SUBMITTED';
```

Now, after 12 hours, this keeps returning 10 times more then it should. Instead of 620 minutes, it returns 6200 minutes. If i do it this way, it works:

```
select time_to_sec(timediff(now(), max(f.SubmittedDate)))/60 FROM dbtable f WHERE f.Status = 'SUBMITTED'
```

I don't understand the difference, why is this happening? Obviously, the lowest timediff should be equal to the timediff between now and the highest date. Am i missing something or is this a bug?

My problem is that i have loads of checks set up this way and editing all of them could be a fair share amount of work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you considered `NULL` values for `f.SubmittedDate`? Just a guess here. Also, `select`ing all the values, and the calculation might help you figure out the problem: `select now(), f.SubmittedDate, max(f.SubmittedDate), etc.`.

Comment: f.SubmittedDate cannot be null (and i have checked it, no value is null). 
I have checked the minimum and the maximum values, but the point is: why is it changing after 12 hours have passed? :( If it would be always wrong, i would have spotted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran some tests on this and your code:

```
select time_to_sec(min(timediff(now(), f.SubmittedDate)))/60 FROM dbtable f WHERE f.Status = 'SUBMITTED';
```

Needs to be:

```
select min(time_to_sec(timediff(now(), f.SubmittedDate)))/60 FROM dbtable f WHERE f.Status = 'SUBMITTED';
```

As you aren't using the "MAX" function like in your second query you need to call the "MIN" function before the "TIME_TO_SEC".

Hope this helps